# For loop for nav-tabs

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have 2 objects in `corporate_goal` and I am trying to execute blocks with this objects in `for loop` like:

```
{% load static %}


{% for goal in corporate_goal %}      

{% block content %}



<!-- Corporate goal section-->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="section-title">
        Corporate Goal: {{goal.corp_goal_title}}
    </div>
    <div style="margin-inline-start:auto">
        {{todo}}0 % of total score TODO
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>HR Rating</p> 
    <p>&nbsp</p>

    {% if goal.corp_factor_rate %}
        <p style="color:mediumspringgreen">rated</p>
    {% else %}
        <p style="color:indianred">unrated</p>
    {% endif %}
    

    <p>&nbsp</p>
</div>

<!-- Tabs for details-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#det1{{goal.corp_goal_title}}">Goal Details</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#det2{{goal.corp_goal_title}}">Other Details</a></li>

</ul>

<!-- Tabs content for details-->
<div class="tab-content" >
    <!--First tab-->
    <div id="det1{{goal.corp_goal_title}}" class="tab-pane fade show active">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Column 1-->
            <div class="col">
                <table class="table-bordless" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <td width="50"></td>
                            <td>{{goal.start_date}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Weight</th>
                            <td width="20"></td>
                            <td>{{goal.corp_factor_weight}} %</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!--Column 2-->
            <div class="col">
                <table class="table-bordless" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <td width="50"></td>
                            <td>{{goal.end_date}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Second tab-->
    <div id="det2{{goal.corp_goal_title}}" class="tab-pane fade" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <p>Factor for Goal Achievement:</p>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{goal.corp_factor_0}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{goal.corp_factor_1}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{goal.corp_factor_2}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{goal.corp_factor_3}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />



{% endblock %}

{% endfor %}
```

In blocks I have `nav-tabs`, but it works only for first object in the loop. Why? Do you have some idea?

[image]

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
```

Comment: Put the for loop inside the content block, blocks should only appear once and I'm surprised you are not getting an error having a block inside a loop

Comment: nothing has changed

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but id attributes should not have white-space, yet `<div id="det1{{goal.corp_goal_title}}"` *will* since `{{ goal.corp_goal_title }}` might have white-space, as in "Networking capital".  Perhaps use the pk of the goal in your id?

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @Shyrokoa!